# javascript async/await ; misunderstanding this code snippet

Tags: javascript, async-await

Why method b excuted before method a ?

And what i do that method a be excuted before method b?

```
const a = () => {
   setTimeout(function(){console.log("method a excuted")},10000)
}

const b = () => {
   console.log("method b excuted");
}

const s = async () => {
    await a();
    await b();
}


s();
result:
method b excuted
method a excuted  //after 10 second
```

Comment: `await` only makes sense when the right-hand side is a Promise

Comment: `a` is executed before `b` in your code but the callback passed to `setTimeout` is executed later. `await` waits for the value returned by `a` to be resolved, and you return `undefined` from `a`.